# Android: Why isnt't the second activity running?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, illegalstateexception

I am working on making my first android app. I am trying to start an activity called `SendMessage` from another activity called `AskReport`. I have seen similar questions like this on SO, but none I could find matches my problem.

The code for `AskReport` activity is as follows:

```
public class AskReport extends Activity
{
    Button done;
    RadioButton checkedRadioButton;
    RadioGroup group;
    EditText email, info;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ask_report);
        done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Report);
        group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        info = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Info);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
        }

    public void reportClick(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SendMessage.class);
/* Line1 */ intent.putExtra("sender_email", email.getText());      
/* Line2 */ intent.putExtra("additional_info", info.getText());    
/* Line3 */ intent.putExtra("checked_button",checkedRadioButton.getText()); 
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The code for activity `SendMessage` is as under:

```
    public class SendMessage extends Activity
    {
    String message = "";
    EditText message_to_send;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.send_message);
        message_to_send = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_to_send);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        message += intent.getStringExtra("sender_email");
        message += intent.getStringExtra("additional_info");
        message += intent.getStringExtra("checked_button");
        message_to_send.setText(message);
        }
}
```

Once i comment out the three lines marked in the `AskReport` activity, the `SendMessage` activity is called successfully, though the text that appears is `nullnullnull`(understandable).

I have marked the activity entries correctly in the manifest.

As an addition, i am also giving here the logcat messages that appear:

```
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     ... 11 more
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.example.safeworld.AskReport.reportClick(AskReport.java:44)
09-10 15:12:57.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     ... 14 more
09-10 15:13:00.725: I/Process(1311): Sending signal. PID: 1311 SIG: 9
```

I have also placed the function in `android:onClick="XXXXXX"` in the corresponding layout.xml.

Please help me figure out what's going wrong in those three lines. Thanks for any help!

Edit:

Here is my `ask_report.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ask"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ask_report"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/road_accident"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/road_accident" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/fire"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/fire" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/theft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/theft" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/other"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:text="@string/other" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AddInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_detail" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AskEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/enter_email"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Report"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/done"
        android:onClick="reportClick" />

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Are you setting `reportClick` to your `Button`'s `android:onClick="reportClick"` And, show us your `XML` code.

Comment: Show us your `ask_report.xml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i thought i would answer this myself and let everyone who reads this know the answer.

The problem with the three marked lines was in `Line3` as that was the one which had `null` value in `checkedRadioButton`.

What worked is:

- I added `android:checkedButton="@+id/road_accident"` to my `RadioGroup` to select the `RoadAccident` by default.
- Next, I added the `onCheckedChangedListener` to the `RadioGroup` which successfully gave me the `checkedRadioButton`.

The code goes as under:

```
group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            }
        });

        checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
```

Now the Line3 would work perfectly fine.

**Credits:**
Thanks @marmor and @SpK for your help. Sorry, couldn't select one of your answers as correct as I took half from both of yours.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the stack trace I would say one of these lines is returning `null`:

```
checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
info = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Info);
email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
```

Print the value of all three views, if one of them is null check the ids are correct and they are in the layout `ask_report`

Comment: Yes you were right. The value of `checkedRadioButton` turns out to be null. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: it means the value returning from group.getCheckedRadioButtonId() doesn't appear in the layout of ask_report. according to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId() it may return -1 if nothing is selected, maybe that's the case.

Comment: Try adding 'android:checkedButton="@+id/road_accident"' to your RadioGroup to select the first item by default

Comment: if this answers your question, please mark is as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

It maybe because of you're getting the text from `EditText` Just do like below -

```
intent.putExtra("sender_email", email.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("additional_info", info.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("checked_button",checkedRadioButton.getText().toString());
```

you forgot to use `.toString()` for getting text from `EditText`

**Update**

Okay, better do like this for getting Text from `radioButton` in a `RadioGroup` Inside of your `Button`'s `onClick` method do like this -

```
// Gets a reference to our radio group
// rBtnDigits is the name of our radio group (code not shown)
RadioGroup g = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1); 

// Returns an integer which represents the selected radio button's ID
int selected = g.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

// Gets a reference to our "selected" radio button
RadioButton b = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected);

intent.putExtra("sender_email", email.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("additional_info", info.getText().toString());

// Now you can get the text or whatever you want from the "selected" radio button
intent.putExtra("checked_button",b.getText());
```

Comment: Its still not working... :(
Also tell me is it okay to use `getText()` with a `RadioButton` ?

Comment: @shrey347 Now, you got new exception or same exception only.

Comment: It was the same exception. Though i have figured out what's going wrong. This is where things are going wrong:
`checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId());`
The value of `checkedRadioButton` is turning out to be null.

Comment: I have tried the update..but the problem is that `g.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` is returning null even when i click on one of the radio buttons. So the value of `selected` is `null`.

Comment: @shrey347 For, this you've to use `onCheckedchangeListener` to get the text from current selected `RadioButton`

Answer (score 0):

Android just implements the OnClickListener for you when you define the

```
android:onClick="someMethod"
```